# symfony2 - radio buttons default data overrides actual value

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a simpleform:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option){
  $builder
    ->setMethod('POST')
    ->add('isdigital', 'choice', array(
      'choices' => array('0' => 'no', '1' => 'yes'),
  'expanded' => true,
      'multiple' => false,
      'data'=> 0
));
}
```

I populate this form passing in an array key value, without using doctrine entities.

```
$this->createForm(new PricingType(), $defaultData);
```

The attribute 'data' should set the value only for the first time, instead overrides the value passed with the array.

If I remove the 'data' attribute, the radio button actually displays the value passed in the array.

Is there any way I can set the default value only for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

In the entity for the data class that related to PricingType add a __construct():

```
__construct(){
    $this->isdigital = 0;
}
```

Now in your controller when you create the $defaultData item which is form the entity Pricing

```
$defaultData = new Pricing();
```

This will have the default value you want and you do not need to have the 'data' => 0 line in your form class.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use an Entity for this form, just pass an array key values

Comment: But you are using something to populate the $defaultData array.  You can add you logic to the set whre you load data into this array.  if the data field is null, then set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is You will need to add a form Event Listener POST_SET_DATA to dynamically set the default value if the values aren't set.
For eg:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents; //Add this line to add FormEvents to the current scope
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent; //Add this line to add FormEvent to the current scope

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $option){
   //Add POST_SET_DATA Form event
   $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,function(FormEvent $event){
       $form = $event->getForm(); //Get current form object
       $data = $event->getData(); //Get current data 
       //set the default value for isdigital if not set from the database or post
       if ($data->getIsdigital() == NULL){ //or $data->getIsDigital() depending on how its setup in your entity class
           $form->get('isdigital')->setData(**YOUR DEFAULT VALUE**); //set your default value if not set from the database or post 
       }
  });
  $builder
    ->setMethod('POST')
    ->add('isdigital', 'choice', array(
      'choices' => array('0' => 'no', '1' => 'yes'),
      'expanded' => true,
      'multiple' => false,
      //'data'=> 0    //Remove this line
 ));
}
```

Please Note: The above code is not tested, but was rewritten to fit the questions scenario.